# Create a permission based system

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions

I'd like to create a system where there are maybe 4-5 types of user groups that can access certain things. The higher the permissions, the more they can do. That's simple to make for me, but the hard part for me is to create the system where the higher ranks can do anything lower ranks can, but lower ranks cannot do what higher ranks can.

I was thinking something like this:

```
if (user.group === "mod" || user.group === "admin"){
  // do stuff
  if (user.group === "admin"){
     // do stuff
  }
}
```

It seems like there's an easier way to do it though.

Comment: Have you looked into using fine-grained permissions instead? That way you are checking if the user can perform some action (e.g. delete blog comments -- which could be set for a blog owner to delete comments on their own blog or an administrator that can delete blog comments on all blogs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try a switch statement?

```
switch(user.group) {
    case 'admin':
        // admin permissions
    case 'mod':
        // admin permission (waterfall effect)
        // mod permission
    case 'user':
        // admin permission (waterfall effect)
        // mod permission (waterfall effect)
        // user permissions
    default:
        // default permissions;
        break;
}
```

I don't see why this couldn't work.

Basically, by not adding `break` to each switch, an admin case will also trigger a mod case and a user case and default with a mod case also triggering a user case etc. etc.

Comment: How would you make it so this doesn't break if there is no user.group assigned?

Comment: It wouldn't. That's why there is the `default` case.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce set of permissions, like `PERMISSION_TO_DO_THING1`, and so on. Next thing - roles, like `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_SPECIAL_GUY`, etc. Each role is a set of permissions. Just take care that higher role contains all the necessary permissions which lower role can do. That is logical thing and it is up to your app and the implementation. Anyway, in the end you need some method like `userHasPermission(user, permission)` and if its `true` - he can do things.

```
if (userHasPermission(user, PERMISSION_TO_ADD_USER)) {
    // do things
}

if (userHasPermission(user, PERMISSION_TO_DELETE_USER)) {
    // do things
}
```